# C++ template static class code generation

Tags: c++, class, templates

Suppose I have a template static class in a "Foo.h" file like following:

```
template<typename T> class Foo
{
    public:
        static T foo1();
        static T foo2();
        static T foo3();
        static T foo4();
        static T foo5();
};

// definitions...
```

Now, suppose I have a "main.cpp" file like this:

```
#include "Foo.h"
main()
{
    double value = Foo<double>::foo3();

    // Do something with value

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this file, will the methods `foo1()`, `foo2()`, `foo4()`, and `foo5()` be also there in the generated code?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the generated code"?

Comment: The code generated by the compiler when you run "g++ main.cpp" for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only `foo3` will be instantiated. Member functions of a class template are treated as separate templates, and each is only instantiated if it's used (or explicitly instantiated).

You can see this yourself by putting code in one of the unused functions which wouldn't compile when instantiated with `double`, like

```
static T foo1() {return T().nonsense;}  // double has no members
```

Your code, which only uses `foo3`, will still compile since it won't try to instantiate this.

Answer (score 3):

No.

> ## C++ Standard 14.7.1/10
>
> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a member template, a non-virtual
>   member function, a member class, or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation. (...)

It is an extremely useful technique, especially combined with policy based design. You can basically define member functions that only work for some template parameters; if you don't use them in such cases you won't get a compile error.

Comment: There is no section 14.7.10.  That is paragraph 10 of section 14.7.1, sometimes abbreviated 14.7.1/10 or 14.7.1p10.

Answer (score 2):

No.

C++ 14.7.1/1-2, emphasis mine:

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but **not** of the definitions or default arguments, of the **class member functions**, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members and member templates; and it causes the implicit instantiation of the definitions of unscoped member enumerations and member anonymous unions.
>
> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, **the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist**....

So your example would even be correct if for example plugging in `double` for the definition `double Foo<double>::foo1()` would cause an error.

On the other hand, if you used an explicit instantiation of the class:

```
template class Foo<double>;
```

then all members are instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily tested. When I put your code in a file and compile it with gcc

```
g++ -g a.cpp
```

I get a binary a.out. Now I can look into it with [`nm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm)

```
nm a.out | grep foo
```

which gives

```
00000000004004dc W _ZN3FooIdE4foo3Ev
```

So, no `foo1` or any other beside `foo3`